# IOS: How to read inputs by hardware from an ios mobile to unity?

Tags: ios, button, unity-game-engine, input, hardware

I need to send a signal from a hardware (a button) to unity. But, I don't know how to start looking into it.

I would have a button (hardware) connected to an ipad or iphone. When I press the button Unity have to read it and do some action.

I don't know if there is an easier way to test it. If I would buy an arduino to do it. Or maybe already exists a pad or something like that to simulate inputs by hardware.

And in that case, how can I read that input from Unity?

I hope I was clear.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an interface between Unity and your hardware device using the Unity Native Plugin Interface.

Then have your hardware talk to that plugin. I've done this a few times for clients' work. It's the same concept on iOS, Android, Mac, PC, and Windows Phone. Probably the same concept on other platforms as well.

[Unity Native Plugin Interface Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePluginInterface.html)